# libGDX: How I can create an one-way platform?

Tags: android, libgdx

How can I create an one-way platform? I want to jump as player through the platform and land on it when the player's falling down. 
Thanks for every comment! :)

Comment: are you dealing with physics body ?

Comment: Could you show what you've tried to do?

Comment: I can't show what I tried to do, because I do not know how I can do this in any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the problem up in pieces and the solution presents itself.

- When player is going up and touching platfrom do nothing.
- When player is going down and touching platform put him on top of it.

The code depends on what you are using for collision. Something along these pseudo lines:

```
if (collision)
{
    if (velocity.y > 0) return;

    if (velocity.y <= 0)
    {
        player.y = platform.top;
        // and/or
        velocity.y = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using box2d in your game you can add `ContactFilter` to physics world and override `shouldCollide` method.

Here is the [Test Class](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/box2d/OneSidedPlatform.java) for the same requirement. Also check this [thread](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13729&p=60534), that may be help you.

Comment: No, I do not use Box2D. Thanks anyway, that you've been busy with my problem. :)